# Indigo fails to load clearpath husky in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, clearpath, husky, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So im trying to migrate over from hydro to indigo, and along with that I am trying to move over my custom simulator packages. Im getting alot fatal errors with trying to run my model with gazebo 2.2 on indigo. But then i realized that the stock Clearpath Husky model that comes from the model database doesnt work either..

Here is the error when I click on the Clearpath model (after gazebo is already open):

```
[FATAL] [1410814234.648936211]: You must call ros::init() before creating the first NodeHandle
[FATAL] [1410814234.648982364]: BREAKPOINT HIT
file = /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-roscpp-1.11.9-0trusty-20140904-2000/src/libros/node_handle.cpp
line=151
```

Not sure what to do, and dont really want to resort to installing hydro from source since i already updated to 14.04 ubuntu.. Anybody having a closing on this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192731/indigo-fails-to-load-clearpath-husky-in-gazebo/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2014-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out that the real problem is loading a model from within gazebo (i.e Insert-->Clearpath Husky) that contains a ROS plugin inside of the model.sdf in the ~/.gazebo/models/(your model). Since after the release of Hydro, Gazebo and ROS are installed as two separate things from each other. Therefore, If you try to "insert" a model when gazebo is already opened, it will give you the error that i received above because you are not running the main component that links gazebo and ROS (since they are independent of eachtoher), "rosGazeboApi".

From my basic understanding and figuring this out, you need to launch your gazebo model from within a ROS launch file using the "spawn_model" node and passing the description of your gazebo model (the .sdf file) as a parameter to spawn_model, which is what solves my problem, IN HYDRO, but since it is the same error, i *think* it should work in indigo as well. This fix should work across all platforms.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1